# Wireless not working properly or directly not working

Tags: networking, wireless, connection, interface

Recently I have bought 2 almost-twins laptops ("HP Stream Notebook PC 13-c102ns" and "HP Stream Notebook PC 13-c100ns") with Win10-64bits as default OS. I tried to install Lubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14.04 and Mint 17 in that order on each one.

The first one just don't allow to configure the wireless because there is no wireless interface to configure, it looks like a non-wireless computer.
The second one allows to connect to an access point and sends and receives data but only during the installation process. After that, it does not connect or it connects just for a few seconds, or it connects but does not handle data.

The problem is exactly the same in all the mentioned OS, except the Lubuntu case which allows to keep the connection for a long but with a very poor quality (with the laptop which could connect during the installation). But the big issue is than the computers have no networking cable entry, so I can't try to solve the problem reinstalling some packets or downloading some drivers.

> Current OS: Ubuntu 14.04.4
>
> "rfkill list all" output (laptop with bad wireless):
>
> ```
> No device blocked
> ```
>
> "rfkill list all" output (laptop with no wireless):
>
> ```
> No bluetooth blocked. The "Wireless LAN" entry does not appear
> ```
>
> "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" output (laptop with bad wireless):
>
> ```
> Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
> Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
> Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
> ```
>
> "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" output (laptop with no wireless):
>
> ```
> Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
> Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
> Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
> ```

Sorry about posting two problems in the same thread but the computers are almost identical and I thought that it could be correct. I will write two different post if necessary, and please tell me about any other command output that you could need.

Thanks so much in advance and sorry about this loooong text and about my bad english.

Have a nice day!

Jano

Comment: Both computers have wireless adapters. Both issues can be solved by installing drivers. But the issues are not related at all.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, thanks for answering. Probably the issue could be solved with new drivers but I don't know how to install them without wired or wireless connection. What new info could I add about the problem?

Comment: Please change this into 2 questions, one for the Broadcom wifi and one for the Realtek but I think if you searched for 14e4:4365 you would find the answer for the Broadcom and search for 10ec:b723 would lead to the fix for the realtek

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a 3g dongle or Ethernet, connect to it and open a terminal then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and WiFi should be working

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I said, the laptops have no ethernet connection so I can't try to play with some drivers. maybe could I install drivers from an USB? is that possible?

Comment: You could try downloading the bcmwl-kernel-source package along with all its dependencies on another device and copy it to your laptop. Then use.     sudo dpkg -i (.deb files)

Comment: I believe *bcmwl-kernel-source* and its dependency *dkms* are on the install USB or DVD.

Comment: That's true. @Jano SuperTrump please follow this link and scroll down until you see ***STA No Internet Access*** your solution is there https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx